# NSMutableRLEArray outof bounds when transitioning views

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller, uiviewanimationtransition

This code is causing my iOS app to crash. The only error I'm getting is `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: 'NSMutableRLEArray objectAtIndex:effectiveRange:: Out of bounds'`
and I can't figure out what's going wrong.

Any ideas?

```
    guard let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow else {
        return
    }
    guard let rootViewController = window.rootViewController else {
        return
    }

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyViewControllerIdentifier")
    vc.view.frame = rootViewController.view.frame
    vc.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    UIView.transition(with: window, duration: 0.3, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
        window.rootViewController = vc
    }, completion: { completed in
        print("completed")
    })
```

EDIT: Oddly enough trying to change ViewControllers with a segue makes the app crash too.

Comment: Perhaps your `Main` storyboard does not have a view controller with the identifier `MyViewControllerIdentifier`

Comment: @daltonclaybrook it does.

Comment: If you add an exception breakpoint in Xcode, you should be able to see the exact line that's causing the crash. Please post if so.

Comment: The last 3 instructions all cause a crash due to an NSRangeException. Commenting some of them didn't help at all